# SyntaxError: invalid syntax python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу никак понять в чем ошибка. Уже все перепробовала

```
nasty = 0
statuses = twitter_api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name=user, count=twt_num, include_rts=False)
for status in statuses:
    if (status.lang == 'en'):  # English tweets
        classes = natural_language_classifier.classify('f48968x109-nlc-5062', status.text.encode(json.dumps(x.decode("utf-8")))
        if (classes["top_class"] == "cyberbully"): 
            nasty += 1
mean = ((float(nasty) / twt_num) * 100)
#if(nasty >= limit):
print '\033[1m' + account.name
print '\033[0m' + "%.0f%% mean tweets" % mean
```

```
File "<ipython-input-44-9acaf21f23e5>", line 6
    if (classes["top_class"] == "cyberbully"): 
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Кстати, если у вас python3, то print нужно использовать со скобками.

Answer (score 2):

Не закрыли скобку в предыдущей строке:

```py
classes = natural_language_classifier.classify('f48968x109-nlc-5062', status.text.encode(json.dumps(x.decode("utf-8"))))
#                                                                                                                      ^
```